HTTP POST Request in Bash - expanding local variable
I am currently trying to submit an HTTP POST request to OpenAI's API endpoint through a bash script.
My current problem is the correct escape syntax expansion for expansion of a local variable TRANSCRIPTION in a JSON object, which contains the content of a parsed text file that is read for the purpose of summary generation:
curl -s -X POST "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions" \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
            -d '{
                "model": "gpt-4",
                "messages": [
                    {"role": "system", "content": "Summarize the following transcription into bullet points of relevant content."},
                    {"role": "user", "content": "$TRANSCRIPTION"}
        ],
            "max_tokens": 100,
        "temperature": 0.7
        }'

I keep receiving the response from the API Endpoint "No content was provided", indicating there is a problem with the variable expansion within the JSON part of the HTTP POST request.

bash does not expand variables in single quotation marks.

I've tried different combinations for "' and "'" as well. In addition, the expansion works very well for the OPENAI_API_KEY variable.

Replace between both ' all " with \" and then replace both ' with ".

try this way '... {"role": "user", "content": "'"$TRANSCRIPTION"'"} ...'

"'" works when I copy and past my curl request to a command line. However, as soon as I put it back into my Bash Script, the API Endpoint would complain about "Invalid JSON payload".

Use a tool like jq that knows how to encode JSON, e.g. curl … -d "$(jq -n --arg content "$TRANSCRIPTION" '{model:"gpt-4",messages:[{role:"system",content:"Summarize the following transcription into bullet points of relevant content."},{role:"user",$content}],max_tokens:100,temperature:0.7}')" …

GitCrush to be clear, that means the advice you got solved the problem you asked about. You now have the new problem that @pmf is helping you solve which is that what your resulting code does will vary greatly based on the contents of the variable TRANSCRIPTION.

please update the question with the output from typeset -p TRANSCRIPTION as well as what you're expecting the curl call to look like with the value of TRANSCRIPTION inserted into the call
